# Create a list of combinations in r with a condition

Tags: r, list, dataframe, combinations

I would like to create a list of all combinations of A, B, and C such that A+B+C=100
This list should be as following.

```
 A  B  C    
 0  0 100
100 0  0
 99 1  0
 98 2  0
 99 0  1
```

I don't know how to approach this problem in R.

Comment: `partitions::compositions(100, 3)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `complete` to generate all the combinations and then do a `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
complete(df1, A, B, C) %>% 
      filter((A + B + C) == 100)
```

---

Or using crossjoin

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, CJ(A, B, C, unique = TRUE)][(A + B + C) == 100]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

If you want unique combinations this works:

```
with(dfa, crossing(A, B, C)) %>%
  filter(rowSums(.) == 100)
```

If you need all the combinations, then try this:

```
with(dfa, expand.grid(A, B, C)) %>%
  filter(rowSums(.) == 100) %>% 
  rename_all(list(~names(dfa)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `expand.grid` + `rowSums` + `subset`

```
out <- subset(
  s <- with(df,expand.grid(A, B, C)),
  rowSums(s) == 100
)
```

or

```
out <- subset(
  s <- do.call(expand.grid,df),
  rowSums(s) == 100
)
```

and you will see

```
> nrow(out)
[1] 5151
```